# C# json serialization and deserialization without attributes

Tags: c#, json

Is it possible serialize and deserialize class and his inheritance without specifying DataMember attribute for every needed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can either use the .NET [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class or use a third-party library such as [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Here is an example using the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "foo",
            Size = 10.5
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = ser.Serialize(dc);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        DerivedClass dc2 = ser.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + dc2.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dc2.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Size: " + dc2.Size);
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public double Size { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{"Size":10.5,"Id":1,"Name":"foo"}

Id: 1
Name: foo
Size: 10.5
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible, i'll give you an example  by writing asp.net code ::

c# code:

```
public class a{
    public prop int id
}

public class b: public a{
    public prop string name 
}
```

asp.net code:

```
@model b    // for taking b as model in this view

<form action="action" method="post" id="myForm">
    enter id : @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.id)
    enter name : @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.name)
<input type="submit" id="send" value="submit">
</form>
```

jquery code:

```
$("#send").click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url:"myURL",
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),     // for serialization of whole form or object b
    success: function(result){},
    }
```

So here the line [data: $("#myForm").serialize()] serialize the whole object b or form "myForm". Here no need to serialize specific attributes.
Hope this helps

Comment: -1. `$(..).serialize();` doesn't serialize to `JSON`. What's more, I suppos that OP want to do serialization at server side.

Comment: Ok. But I need doing this at backend. Is there a way of doing this if I write simple console application? I mean, whole work must performed using only C#.